# How to display row as flex?

Tags: css, wordpress

My row displays the postcard in the archive One under the other https://www.mazkirut.ramothashavim.org.il/improve-my-city/

I tried to add `display: flex;` to row and set the column to `flex: 50%`
but I get weird to behave

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `width: 100%;` to column rather then `flex:50%;`

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove margins form columns. Or do something like this:

```
.row { display: flex; justify-content: space-around; flex-wrap: wrap; }
.column { margin: 0; width: 49%; }
```